# Как в $_GET вывести ключ?

Tags: php, get

Написал такую строку:

```
print_r($id = $_GET);
```

Выводит:

```
Array ( [385] => helloworld )
```

А как достать ключ: 385?

Сделал обход массивов с помощью foreach:

```
foreach($id as $id2){
 echo $id2;
    }
```

Но выводит только значение, а именно `helloworld` а нужен ключ `385`

Comment: `array_keys($_GET);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, это можно сделать так:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    echo $key . " => " . $value;
```

В этом случае сразу получаем и ключи и значения. Если же значения не нужны, то, как верно отметил в комментариях [@Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki), можно использовать функцию [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php):

```
foreach(array_keys($_GET) as $key)
    echo $key;
```

Comment: Понял, а можно еще и так:
`foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    echo $key;`